# I got error message about simulink "Output argument is not assigned on some execution paths"

Tags: matlab, simulink

In simulink, I made some model using "MATLAB function"block
but I met error message here.

### here is code and error message.

```
function [VTAS,postVTAS]=fcn(mode,initialVTAS,a,t,preVTAS)

if mode == 1
     VTAS = initialVTAS + (a * t) ;
     postVTAS = VTAS;

 elseif mode == 2
     datasize = length(preVTAS);
     lastvalue = preVTAS(datasize);
     VTAS = lastvalue + 0;
     postVTAS = VTAS;

 end

 end
```

---

Output argument 'VTAS' is not assigned on some execution paths.

Function 'MATLAB Function' (#36.25.28), line 1, column 26:

"fcn"

### Launch diagnostic report.

I think there is no problem about output "VTAS"

please teach me what is a problems.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler tells you, under some circumstances there is no output value assigned to VTAS. The reason is that you only assign values to that output if mode is 1 or 2. The compiler doesn't know what values are feasible for `mode`. To remedy this, you need to make sure that VTAS is assigned under any and all circumstances.

This could be accomplished by, e.g. adding an else construct, like so:

```
function [VTAS,postVTAS]=fcn(mode,initialVTAS,a,t,preVTAS)

if mode == 1
    VTAS = initialVTAS + (a * t) ;
    postVTAS = VTAS;

elseif mode == 2
    datasize = length(preVTAS);
    lastvalue = preVTAS(datasize);
    VTAS = lastvalue + 0;
    postVTAS = VTAS;

else
    VTAS     = NaN;
    postVTAS = NaN;
end
end
```

**Edit:**

Additionally, it would be good practice for the else case to throw an error. This would be helpful for debugging.

As a minor note, for every case, `postVTAS` is equal to `VTAS`, so essentially it is superfluous to return both from the function.